# Warning creating issue in my app

Tags: android

I have an app in android bcz of these 3 warning my activity showing blank page...

warning are...

```
12-27 12:00:08.741: WARN/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC(135): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
12-27 12:00:08.972: WARN/ActivityManager(71): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
12-27 12:00:09.040: WARN/ActivityManager(71): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{45103338 yes.android.cardholder/.screens.MyWallet}
```

can somebody help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes this exception may arise due to the long running operations. I am sure you are performing long running task on UI thread, instead you can use **`AsyncTask`** to implement long-running task.

Comment: Can u plz tell me another way...bcz my project is very big project near 250 .java classes, so I can't make changes in it..

Comment: @Androo then what should i assume without knowing any bit of code? i have suggested which i have faced already.

Comment: I have used AsyncTask but still its showing these warnings...could u plz tell me the reason.